# Getting the distance of wall(Multiple objects with same tag)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the distance between my player, and the nearest object with the tag 'wall' however I can't seem to get it to work.
To my knowledge my code isn't working at all.
So my question is;
What am I doing wrong? Again, I want to find the distance from my player and the nearest object with the tag 'wall'. If I'm near a object with the tag 'wall' I want it to set the variable to true.(nearWall = true) then once I'm away from the object(About 10.0f) I want it back to false.(nearWall = false)

This is the code I have been working with.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    private float speed = 2.0f;
    private float verticalVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float gravity = 12.0f;

    private bool nearWall;
    public GameObject playerObject;

    GameObject closestObject;

    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;

    public float distanceToWall = Mathf.Infinity;


    private void Start() {
        nearWall = false;
        playerObject = GameObject.Find("Player");

        distanceToWall = 0; 
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }
    public void getNearestWall()
    {
        if (distance <= 10.0f) {
            nearWall = true;
            print ("Near wall!");
        }
        else
            nearWall = false;
    }
    GameObject findNearestWall()
    {
        GameObject[]objectArray;
        objectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wall");

        Vector3 position = playerObject.transform.position;

        foreach(GameObject currentObject in objectArray)
        {
            Vector3 distanceCheck = currentObject.transform.position - position;    
            float currentDistance = distanceCheck.sqrMagnitude;

            if (currentDistance < distance)
            {
                closestObject = currentObject;

                distance = currentDistance;

            }
        }

        return closestObject;
    }
    private void Update() 
    {           
        findNearestWall ();
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        if (controller.isGrounded) 
        {
            verticalVelocity = -0.5f;
        } 
        else 
        {
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            if (!nearWall) {
                if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
                    moveVector.x = speed;
                else
                    moveVector.x = -speed;
            }
            else
            {
                moveVector.x = transform.forward.x * speed;
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
            }
        }
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = transform.forward.z * speed;
        controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using a raycast to measure distance, you won't have to store all the game objects in an array and can be done from player position or from screen out if it is a first person game.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you are not calling getNearestWall() method - which is actually changing the flag - anywhere.
And second why don't you just try:

```
currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(currentObject.transform.position, position);
```

When calculating distance

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to call `getNearestWall();` inside the `Update()` method ( after `findNearestWall()` of course ). also what you are doing now is getting the minimal distance the player reached in the whole game. you might want to add `distance = Mathf.Infinity;` in top of `findNearestWall()` so it will something like this:

```
    GameObject findNearestWall()
{
    GameObject[] objectArray;
    objectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wall");
    distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = playerObject.transform.position;

    foreach (GameObject currentObject in objectArray)
    {
        Vector3 distanceCheck = currentObject.transform.position - position;
        float currentDistance = distanceCheck.sqrMagnitude;

        if (currentDistance < distance)
        {
                closestObject = currentObject;
                distance = currentDistance;              
        }
    }

    return closestObject;
}
```

now whenever you get near a wall it should print `Near wall!`

note:
also you are calling `FindObjectsWithTag()` at an Update method which might significantly drain your processing power. you might want to avoid that by declaring a private `GameObject[] objectArray` in the class. 
and then use `objectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wall");` once at `Awake()` or `Start()`